# Custom settings in Schema.getGlobalDescribe()

Tags: apex

I have a scenario where I am using Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values(). But its returning custom settings also which I don't want in my list. I tried but not getting the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new list by calling isCustomSetting() method in your describe call result. So if its not custom setting use it.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm

Comment: Hi I found Solution for this,

Comment: list<Schema.SObjectType> objectlist=Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();      for(Schema.SObjectType currentobject:objectlist){
        //if(currentobject.getDescribe().isCustom()){
       if(!currentobject.getDescribe().isCustomSetting() && currentobject.getDescribe().isCustom()){
            options.add((new 
          }
        }

Comment: Thats what I have mentioned in the answer. Havent posted code as you havent posted your implementation so wasnt sure how to proceeed.